# Rails: Create a survey with the data in a database table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently trying to create a survey which will use questions that are stored in a table. I've read [nested model form part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) from rails casts however i'm not getting anywhere as the questions are not displaying in the survey.

I have three tables, one tables has the text of the questions, another table keeps the record of who entered the survey and a third table which keeps the answers from a user for the questions.

**variable table**:
name: varchar
id: integer

**report table**
employee name: varchar
date: date
id: integer

**report_variable table**
question_id
report_id
answer

Code i modified for reports/new:

```
 # GET /reports/new
 # GET /reports/new.json
 def new
   @report = Report.new
   #variable = @report.variable.build #dont know what to do here, gives an error with report_id
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # new.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @report }
   end
 end
```

modified report/_form.html.erb

```
   <div >
     <%= f.fields_for :variable do |builder| %>
       <%= render variable_fields, :f => builder %>
     <% end %>
   </div>
```

created report/_variable_fields.html.erb

```
   <p>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
   <p>
```

model for report_variable

```
class ReportVariable < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :report_id, :value, :variable_id
  has_and_belongs to many :reports
  has_and_belongs to many :variables
end
```

model for report

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :employeeName
  has_many :report_variable
  has_many :variable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :report_variable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :variable
end
```

Sorry if it's a simple question, im pretty new to rails.

Comment: Welcome to Rails, what precisely is it that you're unsure about/what isn't working?

Comment: @CyleHunter thank you, i updated the question. The problem is that the questions are not showing up in the survey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Rails!

I think the simple answer is the fields aren't showing up because there aren't any nested records. You can probably get around that by uncommenting the `variable` line as you have it:

```
def new
  @report = Report.new
  @report.variables.build #this line creates 1 new empty variable, unsaved.
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @report }
  end
end
```

If you want more than one variable, call something like:

```
3.times { @report.variables.build }
```

That way the `@report` object you're placing in the form helper will have three variables on it. This should get you moving again, the harder thing is going to be adding ajax addition / removal of variables, but if you know how many there are in advance you don't have to deal with that.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey man, thanks. The thing is that I have some sample data in the variables table, like 3 rows. How can I stablishe the relation? Thx in advance

Comment: You probably want to handle this in the model layer if you've got complex logic going on. Make a method like `load_variables` on report, and put your logic for how you load up the variables there. As long as you've got variables associated with the report when it loads on the page you'll get the nested form correctly.